# adding parameters to pytest setup function

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I am trying to learn pytest, and i'm running into a snag.  I need to define a variable in the setup_method that is defined via a command line parameter.  I am able to do this in individual tests with no problem, but trying to do the same thing in the setup method fails.  I get this message -

```
TypeError: setup_method() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my conftest.py

```
# Conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--var_one", action="store", default=False)
    parser.addoption("--var_two", action="store", default=False)

@pytest.fixture
def var_one(request):
    var_one_param = request.config.getoption("--var_one")
    return var_one

@pytest.fixture
def var_two(request):
    var_two_param = request.config.getoption("--var_two")
    return var_two_param
```

Actualy running the test I do this -

```
py.test --var_one=True --var_two==True tests.py
```

And here is the file, where i would hope the variables are defined and called when the file is executed -

```
import pytest

class Tests:

    def setup_method(self, method, var_one):
        if var_one == True:
            # do stuff
        else:
            # do other stuff

    def test_one(self, var_two):
        assert var_two == True

    def teardown_method(self):
        #Not needed here
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.setup_method()` and `.teardown_method()` functions are the nose-compatibility options and they do not accept fixtures as parameters.  Better would be to use an autouse fixture on the class:

```
class Tests:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def do_stuff_based_on_var_one(self, var_one):
        if var_one:
            # do stuff
        else:
            # do other stuff

    def test_one(self, var_two):
        assert var_two is True
```

As a sidenote, notice that comparing booleans with `==` is considered bad practice, in conditions simply use it's implied truth value.  If you really need to compare it acknowledge it's singleton nature and use object identity with `is`.